# How to change an image every 5 seconds for example?

Tags: javascript, html

I have three images in my HTML code, and I want them to change every five seconds. Why does my code not work?

```js
var images = [];

images[0] = ['photoFromInternet'];
images[1] = ['photoFromInternet2'];
images[2] = ['photoFromInternet3'];
var index = 0;

function change() {
  document.mainPhoto.src = images[index];
  if (index == 2) {
    index = 0;
  } else {
    index++;
  }

  setInterval(change(), 1000);
}

window.onload = change();
```

```html
<div class="lastMain">
  <a href="www.comingsoon.com" id="slider">
    <img id="mainPhoto">
    <div class="mainSlider">
      <img src="photoFromInternet1" style="display: none">
      <img src="photoFromInternet2*" style="display: none">
      <img src="photoFromInternet3" style="display: none">
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

P.S. If you can help please don't use jquery because I haven't learned that yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you should run 'change' function outside of the func and pass the function name to the setInterval func as below

```
let images = ['photoFromInternet', 'photoFromInternet2', 'photoFromInternet3'];

let index = 0;
const imgElement = document.querySelector('#mainPhoto');

function change() {
   imgElement.src = images[index];
   index > 1 ? index = 0 : index++;
}

window.onload = function () {
    setInterval(change, 5000);
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Can you also just tell me what you did here "const imgElement = document.querySelector('#mainPhoto');" ?

Comment: that's query selector to find the dom element. in this case, it is trying to get the image tag element. same as "document.getElementById()"

Comment: I wanted to ask if there is a possible way to stop executing this code in the final image. That would give us a really cool animation.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your console, it's telling you why. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of undefined`, meaning `document.mainPhoto` is undefined. That's not how you select an element in JS (`document.getElementById("mainPhoto")` works better :)

Also, you should *pass* a function to `setInterval`, not call the function directly inside of it, otherwise you are infinitely calling `change()` which leads to an `infinite call stack error`.

Also, if you want 5 seconds, you want to pass 5000, not 1000 (milliseconds).

Finally, you want to set a *timeout*, not an interval, every time you call the function. Timeouts are executed once. If you set a new interval every time, you'll be piling up function calls exponentially, quickly making your page unresponsive by overwhelming the CPU.

```js
var images = [];

images[0] = ['photoFromInternet'];
images[1] = ['photoFromInternet2'];
images[2] = ['photoFromInternet3'];
var index = 0;

function change() {
  document.getElementById("mainPhoto").src = images[index];
  if (index == 2) {
    index = 0;
  } else {
    index++;
  }

  setTimeout(change, 5000);
}

window.onload = change();
```

```html
<div class="lastMain">
  <a href="www.comingsoon.com" id="slider">
    <img id="mainPhoto">
    <div class="mainSlider">
      <img src="photoFromInternet1" style="display: none">
      <img src="photoFromInternet2*" style="display: none">
      <img src="photoFromInternet3" style="display: none">
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining it even more.