# Image swap at each 5 seconds JS

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a website in html. In my header, I want to swap images at each 5 seconds. I found a stackoverflow post ([How to change an image every 5 seconds for example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61957530/how-to-change-an-image-every-5-seconds-for-example)), but the accepted answer didn’t worked. I use w3.css.

This is my actual code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Elonia Network</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylr.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
…
    <header class="w3-display-container w3-content w3-wide" style="max-width:1500px;" id="home">
      <img id="main" class="w3-image" src="images/spawn.png" alt="spawn" width="1500" height="800">
      <div class="mainSlider">
        <img src="images/craft.png" style="display: none;">
        <img src="images/ffa.png" style="display: none;">
      </div>
      <div class="w3-display-middle w3-margin-top w3-center">
        <h1 class="w3-xxlarge w3-text-white">
          <span class="black">
            <b>Elonia Network</b>
            <hr>
            <b>IP: <i>confidential</i></b>
            <b>Port: 19595</b>
          </span>
        </h1>
      </div>
    </header>
```

```js
let images = ["images/ffa.png", "images/craft.png"];

let index = 0;
const imgElement = document.querySelector("#main");

function change() {
  imgElement.src = images[index];
  index > 1 ? index = 0 : index++;
}

window.onload = function () {
  setInterval(change, 5000);
};
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BrBt.jpg)

Comment: Your `change` method is effectively doing nothing. Use a simple logic like `index = index === 0 ? 1 : 0` to make the image alternate between the two that you have in the array

Comment: I posted the output in the question. And if you have an answer, post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be checking whether `index` is bigger than `0`.

Also wrap your code in a `DOMContentLoaded` listener to ensure the elements are loaded when you select them:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let images = ["https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1", "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176"];

  let index = 0;
  const imgElement = document.querySelector("#main");

  function change() {
    imgElement.src = images[index];
    index > 0 ? index = 0 : index++;
  }

  window.onload = function() {
    setInterval(change, 5000);
  };
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Elonia Network</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylr.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  …
  <header class="w3-display-container w3-content w3-wide" style="max-width:1500px;" id="home">
    <img id="main" class="w3-image" src="images/spawn.png" alt="spawn" width="1500" height="800">
    <div class="mainSlider">
      <img src="images/craft.png" style="display: none;">
      <img src="images/ffa.png" style="display: none;">
    </div>
    <div class="w3-display-middle w3-margin-top w3-center">
      <h1 class="w3-xxlarge w3-text-white">
        <span class="black">
            <b>Elonia Network</b>
            <hr>
            <b>IP: <i>confidential</i></b>
            <b>Port: 19595</b>
          </span>
      </h1>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: Would this hold if there are more than two elements?    What if one reaches the end of the array, but I guess the requirement calls for a swap which is limited to two elements...

Comment: @VaheJabagchourian It would not, although it appears from OP's post that they're only dealing with two elements.

Comment: @JSdev What error does it give you? It works in the snippet.