# Automatic graphics change

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I wanted to make a script that automatically changes the graphics on an element, but I stood still and I have no idea what to do with it next.
The script is to retrieve data from the database and include data on:

1. File paths
2. In what order should it appear
3. Display time

The script, after reaching the end of the queue, will run again

PHP CODE:

```
require('require/db/db.php');
$data = date('Y-m-d');
$stmt_take_date = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM upload WHERE screen = 1 AND  end_date >= ?");
$stmt_take_date->execute([$data]);
$row_date = $stmt_take_date->fetchAll();
```

JS:

```
var arraydata = <?php echo json_encode($row_date); ?>;

    arraydata.sort(function(a,b){
        var a1 = a[5], b1 = b[5];
        if(a1 == b1) return 0;
        return a1>b1? 1:-1;
    }); 

var image = [];
    
        arraydata.forEach((ele) =>{
            console.log(ele);
            number = ele[5];
            image[number] = [ele[1],ele[4]];
            
        });
```

console.log(ele):

```
0: "17"
1: "upload/ea435404c4009768432b6f28d9c6a0bd.jpg"
2: "Test"
3: "1"
4: "2"
5: "1"
6: "2022-10-25"
end_date: "2022-10-25"
id: "17"
name: "Test"
queue: "1"
screen: "1"
time: "2"
tmp: "upload/ea435404c4009768432b6f28d9c6a0bd.jpg"
```

I found a lot of entries on a similar topic, but it is based on a fixed display time value

Comment: You don't  need a prepared statement and a bound php variable -- MYSQL/SQL aready has its own way to get the current server date.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

UPD: changed

```
let arraydata = <?php echo json_encode($row_date); ?>;
let currentImage = -1; // the next one will be the first image (on start)
let currentTimer = 0; // time left for current image

const nextImage = () => {
   currentImage = (currentImage + 1) % arraydata.length; // add 1 in circle
   currentTimer = arraydata[currentImage].time;

   document.querySelector('#img').src = arraydata[currentImage].tmp;
}

setInterval(() => {
  currentTimer -= 0.5;
  if (currentTimer <= 0) {
    nextImage();
  }
}, 500);

//call this for init
nextImage();
```

Comment: Fetch in interval is awful idea.

Comment: in the place where 500 is entered, I would like to have a given value for a given photo, e.g. A) photo is displayed 5 sec B) photo is displayed 30 sec

Comment: Don`t say that to the crypto graphics api=)

Comment: So, it`s something like owl-carousel?

Comment: it looks like I have <img> and every specified time for photo number 1 change them after 5 seconds for photo number 2 change them after 10 seconds and it should be displayed alternately.  data about the photo and display time are in array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61957530/how-to-change-an-image-every-5-seconds-for-example
It is very similar, only in this example the frequency is fixed for all photos the same and I would like to achieve something like:
Picture no.1 displays for 5 seconds
Photo no.2
is displayed for 10 seconds

All this is to be displayed in one graphic element to change

Data on how long a given photo is to be displayed is in console.log (ele) named time

Comment: Changed to what you ask.. But you should try to find some library better for that

Comment: ok this work. Do you have some ide. What about mp4 or mov file to display. I mean I want do display jpg png mov and mp4 files

Comment: yes, you can make a container <div id="cnt"></div>. And put the <img src/> or <video>. So, instead of document.querySelector('#img').src  it will be document.querySelector('#cnt')innerHTML = "<img src=..." or <video ...></video>

If I help you - please vote the answer up=)

Comment: It's me again, the only problem is the video because when I want to display it, it either appears after a very long time, but it starts and lasts 1 second and the video is 6 seconds long
I did as commented document.querySelector ('# cnt'). InnerHTML = "<video src = '" + arraydata [currentImage] .tmp + "' </video>";
I also recognized the file extension when jpg ... it's img when mp4 ... it's video.

Comment: https://imgur.com/Wf5DVf5
https://imgur.com/Vxz4Hxn

Comment: It should be: document.querySelector ('# cnt'). InnerHTML = "<video src = '" + arraydata [currentImage] .tmp + "'></video>"; (you miss one "<")

For waiting time you can use a poster:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-poster

Comment: I add autoplay and video still didn't start

Comment: you should add "muted" according to chrome policy