# Retrieving data from an object only works in the original function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm having issues retrieving data from an object using JS on my website. I have a third party scrape Instagram posts and provides JSON to my website via a link. I've managed to retrieve this data from the link and manipulate it, but the problem comes when I try to change the displayed image every 5 seconds.

I took the solution from [How to change an image every 5 seconds for example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61957530/how-to-change-an-image-every-5-seconds-for-example) and tried to adapt for my solution, however, I get an error where `posts[index]` is undefined even though it shouldn't be.

```js
posts = [];
let index = 0;

indexx = 0
$.getJSON('posts.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, f) {
        posts[indexx] = f
        indexx = indexx + 1
    });
});

console.log(posts) // returns all the posts
 
window.onload = change();

function change() {

    console.log(posts) // Returns the list of posts
    console.log(posts[index]) // Returns 'undefined'
    console.log(posts[1]) // Returns 'undefined'
    
    $('#instaimg').attr('src', posts[index]["mediaUrl"])

    if (index == 5) {
        index = 0;
      } else {
        index++;
      }
    
      setTimeout(change, 5000);
}
```

I'm not sure if I am missing something or whether my lack of JS knowledge is to blame, but if anyone could help it would be appreciated

Comment: You call `change` recursively every 5 sec, e.g your call stack will grow indefinitely. Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` instead. Also start the interval inside the `.getJSON` callback function. If you do that outside the data is not there yet

Comment: the console "lies" when you console.log an Object (like an Array is) - if you change the console.log where you commented `// returns all the posts` to `console.log([...posts])`, what do you observe now?

Comment: @JaromandaX i dont get it they are both exactly the same...

Comment: are they? oh, that's weird since you're getJSON is asynchronously adding to posts AFTER you console.log it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues with your code:

- Your `console.log(posts)` will show an empty array because the ajax callback has not finished yet `=>` move that inside the `.getJSON` callback function
- You call `change` recursively every 5 sec, e.g your call stack will grow indefinitely
- Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`
- Start the interval timer inside the `.getJSON` callback function, so that it starts once the fetched data is ready
- Use `.push()` to add to an array, no need to keep track of the index
- Use `$(function() {` to make sure the DOM is ready before you do any action
- You use a hardcoded length 4 for your data length, reference the array size instead

Updated code:

```
let index = 0;
let posts = [];

$(function() {
  $.getJSON('posts.json', function(data) {
    //$.each(data, function(i, f) {
    //  posts.push(f);
    //});
    // It looks like data is the array you want to use, so:
    posts = data;
    setInterval(changeImage, 5000);
  });
});

function changeImage() {
  $('#instaimg').attr('src', posts[index++]["mediaUrl"]);
  if(index > posts.length) {
    index = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this has worked. Just to make a note on your last bullet point, its a hard coded 6, the index starts at zero so when it reaches 5 it will be the 6th iteration.

Comment: Also, it would be `if(index > posts.length - 1)` as `posts.length` = 6 and index will only ever be 5

Comment: No, it's `if(index > posts.length)` because of the `index++` beforehand

Comment: yes, i see what i did wrong, im calling index multiple times during the change function, so i moved index++ to just above the if statement, i just realised now that i could have kept it the same. sorry